# Remove Garbage form Firebird DataBase

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firebird2.1

Firebird 2.1.3 database seems to be creating a lot of garbage from uncompleted transactions this is causing the database to run very slowly until its garbage is removed via a database sweep or server restart. My database size its 30gb+.
Have you any idea what could be causing this?
Do any of the new stored procedures create excess garbage?
Please Help me.?

Answer (score 3):

A Firebird database getting slow after a period of time is usually a sign of bad client transaction management. This can be easily checked by inspecting various transaction counters from the header page, which can be queried by running:

```
gstat -h <yourdatabase>
```

when your database becomes slow. For example: Pretty much all access libraries, when running transactions in auto commit mode (basically when you don't care about starting explicit transactions in your client application), are using COMMIT RETAINING, which basically blocks moving OIT/OAT forward.

Beside the gstat command-line tool, with Firebird 2.1 you also have the monitoring tables, in particular MON$TRANSACTIONS, to identify long-running transactions.

Comment: I need to remove all garbage records from database. Please provide me any way.?

Comment: Run a so-called "Sweep" via e.g. the gfix command-line tool.A sweep basically visits all records in the database and removes out-dated record versions if no concurrent transaction is interested in "seeing" the record version. A sweep is usually most efficient while there are no (long-running) transactions active. Another option is to re-create the database from scratch by running a backup/restore cycle via e.g. the gbak command-line tool.